# Get a single value from a pandas dataframe with a selection based on multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe that is singly indexed and i'd like to select a cell based on the values of two columns in a row. Here's an simple example:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> data_dict = {'A':[11,11], 'B':[22,33], 'C':[44,55]}
>>> df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data_dict)
>>> df
    A   B   C
0  11  22  44
1  11  33  55
```

Given a value for A and B, I want to get the value for C. For example, if I know `A==11` and `B==22`, I want to get `44`. My question is:

**What's the best way of doing this while keeping the index of the dataframe as is?**

I know I can do this through variable attributes but I'm not sure this is the easiest. It seems so messy:

```
>>> df[(df['A']==11) & (df['B']==22)]['C'].item()
44
```

I also know a clean method it to temporarily create a multiindex like below, but I feel like I'm missing something simple about dataframes if I can't get `44` from a singly indexed dataframe without such a complex query.

```
>>> df2 = df.set_index(['A','B'])
>>> df2
        C
A  B
11 22  44
   33  55
>>> df2.loc[11,22].item()
44
```

Thanks!

Comment: I think you can achieve the first thing using pandas [querys](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.query.html)

Comment: Your first method is a very flexible and reliable way to slice a `DataFrame`, though I'd use `.loc` to avoid the chaining. There are many ways to make it more readable. Using the `.col_name` accessors cuts down on a lot of the extra characters. So you could do `df.loc[df.A.eq(11) & df.B.eq(22), 'C'].item()`

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @pazitos10. I think a query made this a lot more readable:

```
>>> df.query('A==11 & B==22')['C'].item()
44
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @ALollz! This selection is also much more readable!

```
>>> df.loc[df.A.eq(11) & df.B.eq(22), 'C'].item()
44
```

I'm glad I asked this question!